# Are oracle OBIEE bundle patches applied consecutively or can you just apply the latest

Tags: oracle, obiee

we have an OBIEE 12.2.1.3.0 server in Linux that currently only has this OBI bundle patch applied:

> 29112070;OBI BUNDLE PATCH 12.2.1.3.190416

Since then, there have been 6 more bundle patches that have been released. I was wondering if each one has to be installed in the order they were released as they are considered cumulative, however on Oracles support site they show that they are all superseded by the latest, because well, they are all older than the latest bundle patch.

The latest patch is #32294042, and I was wondering if just that could be installed as it has these patches listed in the 'Bugs Fixed By This Patch" section:

```
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.201216
 24566569: DRILL-DOWN ERROR: SPECIFIED DRILL-DOWN SELECTION DOES NOT EXIST
 27124002: PROCESSES USING BISERVER SSL STACK  HANG AT 100% CPU WAITING FOR CLIENT DATA
 31448057: Fix for Bug 31448057
 30023519: Fix for Bug 30023519
 26631503: EMAIL BODY IS RENDERING IN ONE LINE, WHEN SETTING EMAIL AS DESTINATION
 31583579: Fix for Bug 31583579
 30909437: Fix for Bug 30909437
 31752569: Fix for Bug 31752569
 31055308: Fix for Bug 31055308
 31689614: Fix for Bug 31689614
 31752589: Fix for Bug 31752589
 31974393: Fix for Bug 31974393
 31752601: Fix for Bug 31752601
 30501937: Fix for Bug 30501937
 31316014: "FILE SYSTEM ERROR WITH OBJECT: /SYSTEM/MKTGJOB/JOB52330" ERROR UPON JOB EXECUT
 32283083: QA[REG]-ADMIN USER NOT ABLE TO DELETE CUSTOM FONTS UPLOADED
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.201020
 29899754: REL13: CHROME: QA:COULD NOT REANME AGENTS IN CATALOG IN CHROME BROWSER
 30029029: CVE-2020-14766
 31312661: CVE-2020-14815
 27733354: REPORT JOB HISTORY DATE FIELD DROPDOWN HAS YEAR 3000 AS DEFAULT.
 27641918: NULL VALUES IN TABLE CAUSE ERROR TO PDF OUTPUT
 27800712: INCOMPATIBLE SORT ORDER ISSUE WITH UNION REPORT IF SET NULL_VALUES_SORT_FIRST=ON
 28047277: OBIEE12C: NON-ADMIN USER GETS "YOU DO NOT HAVE ACCESS PRIVILEGE FOR THIS SA"
 31360445: CVE-2020-11022
 31448181: CVE-2020-14842
 30690685: CVE-2020-14780
 28535009: CHART PROPERTY TREAT NULLS AS ZERO FALSE IS NOT WORKING FOR LINE CHART
 31712733: TRACKING BUG TO INCLUDE BUG 30690685 FOR BIMAD
 31637106: CVE-2020-14864
 30865195: CVE-2020-14784
 31448244: CVE-2020-14843
 28996803: BISERVER_MAIN_WINDOWS LABEL BUILD FAILURE
 31087358: CVE-2019-11358
 31747467: CVE-2020-14879
 31752545: CVE-2020-14880
 31858931: 12214[REG][-BIMAD-MOBILE APP CREATION FAILING IN LATEST OCTIBER BUNDLE PATCH
 30763883: Fix for Bug 30763883
 30763870: CVE-2019-1547
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.200714
 31024106: CVE-2020-14609
 26556686: SFTP TEST CONNECTION FAILS FOR PRIVATE KEY AUTHENTICATION
 27658023: R13 UNABLE TO FORMAT FILENAME WHILE SETTING UP REPORT JOB - UCM/SFTP DESTINATION
 27137133: BIP REPORT REQUEST FAILS FOR THE FIRST TIME VIA /ANALYTICS THROUGH LOAD BALANCER
 27539559: ERROR - STRING INDEX OUT OF RANGE : -31 WHEN REPORT IS CREATED WITH SUBJECT AREA
 27501735: 12C SYSDATE STILL BEING SHOWN AS {$SYSDATE()$} IN JOB HISTORY
 27545920: GUEST REPORT ACCESS ERROR
 30971776: CREATE AGENT => ANALYTICS HANG & ERROR : [LDAP: ERROR CODE 11 - ADMINISTRATIVE LIMIT EXCEEDED]" AFTER 12.2.1.4.200114 + DIAGNOSTIC PATCH FROM BUG 30903799
 30865185: CVE-2020-14585
 30865177: CVE-2020-14584
 30690694: CVE-2020-14571
 31418768: CVE-2020-14696
 29631418: CVE-2020-14548
 29873706: CVE-2019-14862
 29820321: BEFORE REPORT TRIGGER EXECUTES AFTER BURSTING SQL
 28885154: BI PUBLISHER REMOVES RANDOM SPACES FROM RTF LAYOUT AFTER UPLOAD
 26492182: PRIVATE KEY AUTHENTICATION WORKING ON ONE POD AND NOT ON 3 OTHERS FOR SAME CUST.
 30690687: CVE-2020-14570
 31405776: FIX 26556686 - SFTP PRIVATEKEY ISSUES - 12.2.1.3.200714
 30579384: OBIEE 12.2.1.4: EXPORT TO EXCEL AND PDF PROPERTIES ARE NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
 27035568: 17.4.5-1164 : REPORT WITH LAYOUT TEMPLATE GETS CORRUPTED WHEN JUST OPEN AND SAVE
 25896614: PDF FILES NOT WORKING AS TEMPLATES WHEN SAVED AS ADOBE ACROBAT DC 11 PRO FILES
 27693385: INSECURE STRUTS 1.3 JARS STILL BE SHIPPED BY BITHIRDPARTY
 31212299: Fix for Bug 31212299
 31374057: CVE-2020-14690
 31358667: CVE-2020-14626
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.200414
 22119433: BISERVER_MAIN:CRASH IN NQSSERVER
 26832490: AFTER APPLYING PATCH 23299204 OK BUTTON DISABLED IN PARENT-CHILD HIERARCHY
 30693647: 2.5 Authorization Bypass (Vertical Escalation)
 25359947: MOUSE DISAPPEARS AFTER MOVING COLUMNS AROUND ON A DASHBOARD 6-10 TIMES
 27960353: Fix for Bug 27960353
 27365263: NEED TO ALLOW OBIS STARTUP TO CONTINUE EVEN THERE IS A CYCLE IN ROLE HIERARCHY
 30961988: CVE-2020-2950
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.200114
 28747707: CVE-2020-2531
 25826028: UNABLE TO QUERY RECIPIENT NAMES BY DISPLAY NAME ATTRIBUTE
 27472788: OBIEE 12C: ROLES GRANTED ON "VIEW DELIVERS FULL UX" LOST AFTER RESTART
 27443959: LINE IN GRAPH LINE IS NOT DISPLAYED IN IE11 IN HTML5 MODE
 27345574: SAWLOG FILLS UP WITH:  A TYPE MISMATCH OCCURRED WHILE EVALUATING AN EXPRESSION
 26355617: CAN'T SELECT TABLE PROMPTS DROPDOWN LIST VALUE ON IE11
 23211224: BICS PROMPT BASED ON TIMESTAMP DATATYPE COLUMN  ERRORS WITH INVALID PROMPT VALUE
 30374407: CVE-2020-2537
 29879085: CVE-2016-1000031
 27097220: HUGE NUMBER OF NOTIFICATION LOG ENTRIES FOR CONNECTION POOL EVENTS
 27311972: IMPLEMENT RUNTIME EVALUATION OF DYNAMIC REPOSITORY VARIABLES
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.191015
 24415058: CVE-2015-7940
 29780273: CBIL:11.13.19.01.0:CRM: REMOVE MESSAGE: COPY LINK REQUIRES ADOBE FLASH PLAYER
 28709953: CVE-2019-2898
 29506719: CVE-2019-1559
 29953527: DISABLE ADOBE FLASH IMAGE SUPPORT IN ANSWERS
 28627478: CVE-2019-2905
 29488979: CVE-2019-1559
 29506769: CVE-2019-1559
 28722735: CVE-2019-2900
 28831894: CVE-2019-2897
 29827791: CVE-2016-7103
 29750683: CVE-2020-2535
 28565865: CVE-2019-3012
 30380250: QA: CI BUG 30054026 IS NOT FIXED IN 9.191015
 26382244: DISABLE FLASH TEMPLATE IN OAC
 26551071: QA:UPLOAD TEMPLATE TEXT NEED TO BE MODIFIED AS FLASH TEMPLATE IS DISABLED
 27440571: FLASH CONFIGURATION SHOULD BE REMOVED FROM OAC RUNTIME PROPERTIES
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.190716
 28900868: CVE-2019-2771
 28886045: CVE-2019-2768
 28885772: CVE-2019-2767
 27839392: Fix for Bug 27839392
 27580645: JNDI DATASOURCE ISSUE WITH PRE-PROCESS FUNCTION
 29509993: CVE-2019-2906
 27788081: CVE-2019-2742
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.190416
 25248099: NEED TO CHECK THE RETURN CODE OF BUILDROLEHIERARCHY
 28797734: CVE-2019-2605
 28885971: CVE-2019-2616
 28722734: CVE-2019-2595
 28627487: CVE-2019-2588
 28747876: CVE-2019-2601
 28077156: CVE-2015-9251
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.181016
 27747746: Fix for Bug 27747746
 26560302: Fix for Bug 26560302
 27826864: Fix for Bug 27826864
 27826858: Fix for Bug 27826858
 27826869: Fix for Bug 27826869
 27747600: Fix for Bug 27747600
 28143150: CVE-2018-8013
 26957199: CVE-2017-5645
 28095823: CVE-2018-3204
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.180717
 27019889: DYNAMIC REPOSITORY VARIABLES NOT WORKING IN 12.2.1.3.0
 24623887: CVE-2017-10060
 21216069: GRAPH CANNOT BE DISPLAYED IF DISPLAY VARIABLE IS SET
 27155012: OBIS SESSION SWITCH DOES NOT CARRY OVER DEFAULT SUBJECT AREA
 25071445: CRITICAL JOBS SHOULD NOT BE SHOWN WITH RED BACKGROUND ON JOB HISTORY PAGE
 25484519: MAINTENANCE FLAG NEEDS TO BE CHECKED WHEN BIEE CONNETION FAILS
 21309457: SSBEN ACCESSIBILITY: BIP REGION HAVING FORM AND STRUCTURE INSPECTOR ISSUE
 26798068: HCMANALYTICS DEPLOYMENT ON 12CIWS FAILED WITH UNRESOLVED APPLICATION LIBRARY REF
 27529288: 12C SMC PILLAR ESS APPS DEPLOYMENT UNKNOWNHOSTEXCEPTION: SLC01HJK.US.ORACLE.COM
 26909225: CVE-2018-2925
 27679984: CVE-2018-2958
 
OBI Bundle Patch 12.2.1.3.180116
 24691274: CONFIG.XML FOR BI-ADF BROKER JDEV EXTENSION HAS AN ILLEGAL SPECIFICATION-VERSION
 26266824: OBIEE 12.2.1.2.0  AN HTTP OPERATION TO XXXX.EMEA.XXX.LOC:80 TIMED OUT AFTER 1SEC
 26486161: PS: PDFDOCMERGERV2/PDFMERGER ERRORS AND FAILS TO MERGE SOME PDF-CREATED BY LATEX
 26171147: CALENDAR IS NOT UPDATED IN SEEDED REPORTS
 26760055: PSR:PERF:BICS CLUSTER CONTROLLER SHOULD WAIT/ LOG/ RETRY BEFORE TAKING OBIS OFFL
 26578260: SESSIONS IN OBIEE12C DO NOT FAIL-OVER GRACEFULLY WHEN ONE NODE IS KILLED
 26975548: ADMINTOOL COMPARE NOT PULLING IN ALL DIFFERENCES IN RPDS
 21766173: CVE-2016-3473
 21766306: CVE-2016-0470
 26535378: EL 12 UPGRADE A? LINKED ANALYSES NOT WORKING FROM HUMAN RESOURCES DASHBOARD
 26944921: EEAR-TEST:CANCEL QUERY DOES NOT WORK
 26017396: OBIEE 12C: CUSTOM SKIN / STYLE SET IN RPD VARIABLES IS NOT APPLIED TO DASHBOARDS
 26541044: CVE-2018-2715
 26775946: INCREASE THE DEFAULT VALUE OF OBIS_MAX_PERIODICTASKS_EXECUTOR_THREADS
 25061256: CVE-2017-10068
 26553225: CVE-2017-5662
 26787841: Fix for Bug 26787841
 26923935: 12C DEPLOYMENT - BIADMINESSBASERULEGENERATOR LIBRARY MISSING
 26787682: Fix for Bug 26787682
 26612444: HIDDEN DASHBOARD PAGE IS ADVERSELY AFFECTING DASHBOARD NAVIGATION.
 27214490: SEVERE: EMBEDDED EXPORT SPECIFICATION JAR:BIADMINESSBASERULEGENERATOR.JAR
 26632162: Fix for Bug 26632162
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle Patches are always cumulative. You can install the last one.

Generally you should try to stay up-to-date. it's not just application bugs which are fixed but also security bugs. The closer you stay to the current patch level the more secure you are.

Comment: OK, that's what was throwing me off. They're cumulative meaning each one contains the previous ones patches plus it's new patches. I was reading it as each bundle patch would have to be installed successively to be cumulative.  We update WLS quarterly, but just inherited the responsibility of doing OBI for the group now too, so we have a ways to get caught up. Thanks!

Comment: OBI BPs normally stay in line with WLS anyways as it uses WLS as its backend.